# How to insert text in mysql without adding slashes

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code and i am submitting **sunny \ "** in textarea

```
<html>
  <head>
         <title>mysql Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
         $d=$_GET['s'];
         require("sql.php");
         mysql_query("insert into test value(NULL,'".mysql_real_escape_string($d)."')",$cn);
    ?>
    <form name="form1" method="get" action="">
        <textarea name="s"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i look at inserted text in phpmyadmin it looks as

```
sunny \\ \"
```

but i want orignal string like

```
sunny \ "
```

> Note: magic_quotes_gpc is off in php.ini

Comment: use `stripslashes()`..http://www.php.net/stripslashes

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 tried this but didn't works

Comment: use perpared queries, and don't use mysql_..., at the very least use msqli_..., or just use the PDO concept. Both are explained in on the excellent php.net manual subpages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using PDO for this.  The mysql_* functions are deprecated and open your code up to all sorts of SQL injection trouble.

```
// code here to connect to your database
...

// create a new statement
$d = $_GET['s'];
$sth = $dbh->prepare("insert into test values(null,:s,:cn)");
$sth->bindParam(":s",$d);
$sth->bindParam(":cn",$cn);
$sth->execute();
```

If magic quotes are truly turned off, the PDO methods above should take care of escaping the values and inserting them without the extra slashes

---

Also take care that your application does not rely on [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/magic_quotes) and those are turned off because it's a big security mistake that has been introduced in PHP which has been reverted since some time then (see the warnings and explanations linked).

Comment: @hakre, if you want to add an answer, please add your own answer or post a comment. Stop adding text to my answer.

Comment: The SQL injection trouble does not just vanish only because you change the PHP database client library, however, what PDO offers which mysql_* does not offer are parametrized queries.

Comment: Sure, if I would I would have done. For more please consult the help section, http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing - *"[...] Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. [...]"* - I think it's important to make visible that magic quotes are not entirely OPs fault.

Answer (score -2):

not a good way though but will work for you this way

```
 $d=$_GET['s'];
 $a = stripslashes($d);
 $b = $t. " \\"."\\";
 mysql_query("insert into test value(NULL,'".mysql_real_escape_string($b)."')",$cn);
```

this will give you a single "\" in your dtabase

Comment: Mysql_* functions are deprecated.